# Regular Expression to Capture specific set of IP Address in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

My output is as below

```
0.0.0.0/0
  unicast-ip4-chain
  [@0]: dpo-load-balance: [proto:ip4 index:86 buckets:1 uRPF:102 to:[0:0]]
    [0] [@0]: dpo-drop ip4
0.0.0.0/32
  unicast-ip4-chain
  [@0]: dpo-load-balance: [proto:ip4 index:87 buckets:1 uRPF:88 to:[0:0]]
    [0] [@0]: dpo-drop ip4
1.1.1.254/32
  unicast-ip4-chain
  [@0]: dpo-load-balance: [proto:ip4 index:72 buckets:1 uRPF:41 to:[0:0]]
    [0] [@5]: ipv4 via 2.2.2.254 VirtualFuncEthernet0/7/0.1540: mtu:1500 f8c001181ac0fa163e81a6c0810006040800
14.1.1.0/32
  unicast-ip4-chain
  [@0]: dpo-load-balance: [proto:ip4 index:14 buckets:1 uRPF:111 to:[0:0]]
    [0] [@0]: dpo-drop ip4
14.1.1.1/32
  unicast-ip4-chain
  [@0]: dpo-load-balance: [proto:ip4 index:54 buckets:1 uRPF:61 to:[1228:75011]]
    [0] [@5]: ipv4 via 14.1.1.1 VirtualFuncEthernet0/7/0.1540: mtu:1500 f8c001181ac0fa163e81a6c0810006040800
```

To capture the value 2.2.2.254 from the output I have written regexp as below.

```
var = 1.1.1.254/32
re.findall(var+r'.*ipv4\s+via\s+(\W+)', x1)
```

Current output is []

Comment: Unless you are *specifically* asking about how to solve a cross-version compatibility problem (in which case your question should obviously describe that problem) you should not mix the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tags. I have edited to remove the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?ms)^1\.1\.1\.254/32\n.*?ipv4\s+via\s+(\d[\d.]*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/66soZ0/1)

**Details**

- `(?ms)` - `re.M` and `re.DOTALL` enabled
- `^` - start of a line
- `1\.1\.1\.254/32` - `1.1.1.254/32` string
- `\n` - a newline
- `.*?` - any 0 or more chars as few as possible
- `ipv4\s+via\s+` - `ipv4`, 1+ whitespaces, `via`, 1+ whitespaces
- `(\d[\d.]*)` - Capturing group 1: a digit and then 0 or more digits / dots

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/xFAHCt):

```
import re
text = "0.0.0.0/0\n  unicast-ip4-chain\n  [@0]: dpo-load-balance: [proto:ip4 index:86 buckets:1 uRPF:102 to:[0:0]]\n    [0] [@0]: dpo-drop ip4\n0.0.0.0/32\n  unicast-ip4-chain\n  [@0]: dpo-load-balance: [proto:ip4 index:87 buckets:1 uRPF:88 to:[0:0]]\n    [0] [@0]: dpo-drop ip4\n1.1.1.254/32\n  unicast-ip4-chain\n  [@0]: dpo-load-balance: [proto:ip4 index:72 buckets:1 uRPF:41 to:[0:0]]\n    [0] [@5]: ipv4 via 2.2.2.254 VirtualFuncEthernet0/7/0.1540: mtu:1500 f8c001181ac0fa163e81a6c0810006040800\n14.1.1.0/32\n  unicast-ip4-chain\n  [@0]: dpo-load-balance: [proto:ip4 index:14 buckets:1 uRPF:111 to:[0:0]]\n    [0] [@0]: dpo-drop ip4\n14.1.1.1/32\n  unicast-ip4-chain\n  [@0]: dpo-load-balance: [proto:ip4 index:54 buckets:1 uRPF:61 to:[1228:75011]]\n    [0] [@5]: ipv4 via 14.1.1.1 VirtualFuncEthernet0/7/0.1540: mtu:1500 f8c001181ac0fa163e81a6c0810006040800"
v = "1.1.1.254/32"
m = re.search(rf"^{re.escape(v)}\n.*?ipv4\s+via\s+(\d[\d.]*)", text, re.M|re.DOTALL)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
# => 2.2.2.254
```

Comment: how can we capture the multiple IP, if I have to capture multiple IP.
eg : 

`1.1.1.254/32
  unicast-ip4-chain
  [@0]: dpo-load-balance: [proto:ip4 index:214 buckets:4 uRPF:230 to:[0:0]]
    [0] [@5]: ipv4 via 2.2.2.254 Interface0/6/0.2000: mtu:1500 f8c001189ac0fa163e77d390810005e40800
    [1] [@5]: ipv4 via 3.3.3.254 Interface0/6/0.2001: mtu:1500 f8c001189ac0fa163e77d390810005e50800
    [2] [@5]: ipv4 via 4.4.4.254 Interface0/6/0.2002: mtu:1500 f8c001189ac0fa163e77d390810006300800
    [3] [@5]: ipv4 via 5.5.5.254 Interface0/6/0.2003: mtu:1500 f8c001189ac0fa163e77d390810006310800`

Comment: Written a regexp as below as below for the same, to capture `2.2.2.54, 3.3.3.254, 4.4.4.254, 5.5.5.254`
[Python Code for the same](https://ideone.com/PrmuVL)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the whole block of text until next IP try this:
https://regex101.com/r/wCHYvj/2

`(1\.1\.1\.254\/32)(\s*|.*)+?(?=\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})`

find given IP and capture until next IP in new line

Comment: `(\s*|.*)+?` will lead to huge performance issues and catastrophic backtracking with non-matching inputs.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew good point, thx. I'll edit my answer